# Notice: Undefined index with used isset and $_GET

Tags: php

this is my code

```
if(isset($_GET['delt']) || isset($_GET['editt'])){
    $delt = intval($_GET['delt']);
    $editt = intval($_GET['editt']);
}
```

when run the code I get the error

> Notice: Undefined index: delt in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/tel-s/admin/top_a.php on line 116

I'm confused because i use `isset` and test used `empty` but do get the same problem

Comment: Use ` && ` instead of ` || `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check both of variables for exists or change code

```
if( isset($_GET['delt']) ) {
    $delt = intval($_GET['delt']);
  }
  if ( isset($_GET['editt']) ) {
    $editt= intval($_GET['editt']);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your are testing only if one of params is set and later use both of them no matter if it's actually set.

Use `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or):

```
if (isset($_GET['delta']) && isset($_GET['editt']))
```

OR

```
if (isset($_GET['delta'], $_GET['editt']))
```

Answer (score 0):

It must have gotten `$_GET['editt']` but couldn't get `$_GET['delt']` and threw an error because it couldn't set anything to `$delt`. Consider @Justinas' answer.

Answer (score -1):

did your url contains both "delt" and "editt" parameters ?
what is the out put of print_r($_GET) ?
isset function checks whether a variable is set or not ? 
if you pass a string to intval() it will return 0